# IIS Windows Authentication before Anonymous

Tags: windows, iis, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have a website that I would like to allow both Forms and Windows Auth for. My problem is that it seems that when you setup IIS to allow both anonymous (Required for forms auth) and Windows auth that the browser won't send the user's network credentials.

It just uses the anonymous login. Is there any way either in IE8 or IIS to have it try Windows Auth 1st and then fall back to Anonymous?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to support NTLM authentication with fall-back to form in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027911/how-to-support-ntlm-authentication-with-fall-back-to-form-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 11):

You can't ask for HTTP authentication (whether that's Basic Authentication or Integrated Windows Authentication) without causing the authentication dialogue box to pop in the case where there are no credentials yet.

So in general for hybrid HTTP-auth+cookie-auth approaches you enable both anonymous and authenticated access for the bulk of the site, but allow only authenticated access to one particular script.

When the user accesses a page without either kind of auth, you spit out a page with a login form for the cookie-based auth, and also a link to the one URL that allows only authenticated access. The user can fill out the form for cookies&forms auth, or hit the link to log in with HTTP auth instead.

If the user follows that link, they will be given a `401` response and must provide HTTP authentication, either through the auth dialog, or potentially automatically using integrated Windows authentication. Once this has happened once, the browser will start submitting the same credentials to every future page, so IIS will decode the credentials to give you the expected `REMOTE_USER` when your main site scripts are run.

Browsers will only submit the credentials to pages in the same directory as the `401` script, or subdirectories of this. For this reason it is best to put the HTTP-auth-required script in the root, for example as `/login.aspx`.

However, there are a few browsers that won't automatically submit credentials for further pages, and require every HTTP request to respond `401` first, before sending the request again with credentials. This makes optional-auth and hybrid-auth schemes impossible (as well as making browsing of protected sites much slower!). The only modern browser that does this is Safari. You may not care, as Safari's support for Integrated Windows Authentication has traditionally been shaky anyway, and it can still use the forms+cookies auth type.